# Run 2 instances of webdriver on the same machine at the same time

Tags: parallel-processing, selenium-webdriver

It's like this.

I have 2 different processes. One starts a ChromeDriver, the other starts an IEDriver. When the processes start to work, it's as if the one that started earlier jumps into the browser that was started later, and the actions of the Chrome process are done in the IE browser, while the IE process gets disconnected from the browser. And then an error appears in the first one too, like StaleElementException. Different errors, but also a fail for other combinations, including Firefox.

Are the webdrivers sharing some resources behind the scene (port, socket, windowhandle, profile)?

How can I accomplish a parallel independent run? What about using 2 instances of the same webdriver?

(Running all this in C# with MsTest)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using protractor and I can run a lot of instances of webDriver with this configuration in my configuration file.

```
exports.config = {
    framework: 'jasmine',
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    specs: [],
    multiCapabilities: [{
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        'specs': ['protractor-spec.js'],
        'count': 5, //number of instances
        'shardTestFiles': true, //execute instances of browser simultaneously
    },
```

**count** is the number of instances you want launched.